# How can i replace many identical conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `running` variable which is responsible for whether the program is running or not. There is also a loop that runs as long as `running == True`. This loop contains many functions, each of which takes, say, 1 second to complete.

Thus, if during the iteration of the loop the value of `running` is changed to `False` until the iteration is completely completed, the actions will be performed.

It is necessary for me that as soon as the value of `running` becomes `False`, the cycle is interrupted immediately (well, or almost immediately).

I have this solution:

```
running = True

while running:
    do_something1(time_length=1)
    if not running:
        break

    do_something2(time_length=1)
    if not running:
        break

    do_something3(time_length=1)
    if not running:
        break

    do_something4(time_length=1)
    if not running:
        break

    do_something5(time_length=1)
    if not running:
        break

    do_something6(time_length=1)
    if not running:
        break

    # etc.
```

However, this option looks very clumsy and takes up a lot of space. Is it possible not to prescribe a condition before each action, but to prescribe it, say, only at the beginning?

**UPD 1:**
Due to the fact that I did not fully show the code, the answers do not quite suit me, as I understand it.

All variables and functions are inside the class. The code itself looks like this.

```
from threading import Thread


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = True

    def toggle_running_flag(self):
        # this function toggles self.running by user input
        self.running = not self.running
        if self.running:
            Thread(target=self.do_all_of_this).start()

    def do_something1(self):
        # do something
        pass

    def do_something2(self):
        # do something
        pass

    def do_something3(self):
        # do something
        pass

    def do_all_of_this(self):
        while self.running:
            self.do_something1()
            if not self.running:
                break

            self.do_something2()
            if not self.running:
                break

            self.do_something3()
```

Comment: Make a list with `do_something` functions and call them in a for loop.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem, yes, I thought about it, but isn't there a more elegant option?

Comment: Not really. This is the kind of thing that could be done with macros, but Python doesn't have macros.

Comment: @Barmar, understood, thanks.

Comment: Is 'do_something' is the always the same function or they are totaly different?

Comment: @Fredericka, functions are completely different.

Comment: Raising an exception is generally a much easier way to interrupt a control flow than constantly checking a flag.

Comment: @Samwise Yeah but you program has to check a flag to know when raise error?

Comment: @Fredericka The idea is that you raise the error instead of setting the flag in the first place.  (Doesn't work across threads per OP's latest edit, though.)

Comment: @Mus1k check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is a way you can do that. You can create a function that will loop indefinitely between the functions you have to execute:

```
from itertools import cycle

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = True

    def toggle_running_flag(self):
        # this function toggles self.running by user input
        self.running = True
        Thread(target=self.do_all_of_this).start()

    def do_all_of_this(self):
        self.work = [self.do_something1, self.do_something2, self.do_something3]

        for func in cycle(self.work):
            func()
            if not self.running:
                return
```

After every iteration check if your program should still be running. If not return (Stop iteration)

Comment: You could also use `for func in itertools.cycle(work)` instead of having both the while and for loop

Comment: @Fredericka, but why use `cycle()`? Why can't i just use `for func in self.work`?

Comment: @Mus1k When you loop through a list it ends a the end of the list. In this case we want it to cycle indefinetly. The simple for loop would give (1,2,3), the cycle gives (1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3, etc)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of that flag variable, you could use an exception. Note that exceptions aren't just for "bad stuff", for example the `StopIteration` exception is how iterators signal that they're done.

Demo:

```
from contextlib import suppress

class StopRunning(Exception):
    pass

def do_something1():
    print('do_something1')
    raise StopRunning

def do_something2():
    print('do_something2')

with suppress(StopRunning):
    while True:
        do_something1()
        do_something2()

print('done')
```

Output:

```
do_something1
done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY69DsIwDIT3PEW2piNlQey8ALCj0rokUmtbiauWpw8pP1X5EbfZd/58fBVLuN6wj7Hx1OmKUGCU1p2165i86NAzewhBqaotQ9AHId73iA4vZjdWwOII863SSVxOuRoaXdMpUAdiU2xlXrZ3KCZ787L8bvnSBViyvzHFH0yRMGpwYue6ZsF63g3WtaCPvofHPOmj5899eqzU/BQhy2O8AQ)

Comment: Where do you check the Running condition? What if you want to run multiple time the do_something, where do you put the raise

Comment: @Fredericka I'd say "check" and "condition" are not what's happening. Instead, the exception is raised (by the code that previously set the `running` variable to `False`) and then caught/suppressed by the `suppress` context manager.

Comment: @Pychopath, i'm sorry. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Pychopath, i need the main loop to be inside a function and run with `threading.Thread()`
Can I use the `with suppress(StopRunning)` construct inside a function that is also started with `threading.Thread()`?

Comment: @Mus1k I don't see why not. Though if you want that `running` variable not just as you originally showed but also for that toggling business, then I'd say go with Fredericka's method. Particularly now that you also showed that the `do_something`s are not just representing arbitrary code but actually are just function calls.

Comment: @Pychopath, understood, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are the various `do_something`s setting `running = False`? Relying on globals isn't a great pattern.

One alternative to updating a global flag is to have `do_somethingN` throw an exception to stop execution:

```py
from do_things import StopRunning, do_something1, do_something2, # etc
try:
    while True:
        do_something1(time_length=1)
        do_something2(time_length=1)
        do_something3(time_length=1)
        do_something4(time_length=1)
        do_something5(time_length=1)
        do_something6(time_length=1)
except StopRunning:
    pass
```

Elsewhere:

```py
# do_things.py
class StopRunning(Exception):
    pass

def do_something1(time_length):
    if time_length > 42:
        raise StopRunning

# etc
```